# Waiting for loop to finish and then taking the data from it

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, for-loop

I'm making discord bot in which I have loop to loop through my JSON data. That works fine however I want to paste that data to Hastebin.

```js
const emails = require("../../json/emails.json");
const hastebin = require("hastebin-gen");

for (var obj in emails) {
    if (emails.hasOwnProperty(obj)) {
        for (var prop in emails[obj]) {
            if (emails[obj].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                var results = emails[obj]["email"]
            }
        }
    }
    var haste = await hastebin(results, { extension: "txt" });
}

console.log(haste)
```

JSON

```
{
    "test": {
        "email": "test@gmail.com"
    },
    "Test1": {
        "email": "mhm@gmail.com"
    }
}
```

As you can see I have 2 emails in JSON so it creates 2 hastebin links and in them is always only 1 email.

**EDIT**
Didn't really say what is the problem. I want to log only 1 Hastebin url with all the emails inside. Not 2 Hastebin urls and each one has only 1 email.

Comment: Well, you have only one `var haste` in your code. Maybe you want to collect the results in an array? Or just log the `haste` during each iteration, instead of after loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to push all promises to an array and then use [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) to wait for all of them to be fulfilled or rejected:

```
const emails = require("../../json/emails.json");
const hastebin = require("hastebin-gen");

const promises = Object.values(emails).map(({ email }) => hastebin(email, { extension: "txt" }));
const results = await Promise.allSettled(promises);

console.log(results);
```

According to your comments, if you want to generate a single Hastebin, then you should move the `hastebin` call after the `for` loop and pass it all the `results` concatenated:

```
const emails = require("../../json/emails.json");
const hastebin = require("hastebin-gen");

const content = Object.values(emails).map(({ email }) => email).join('\n');
const results = await hastebin(content, { extension: "txt" });

console.log(results);
```

Comment: Find out this still code still logs for every new update new Hastebin. Must untag as a solution.

Comment: @txshiro Not sure what you mean. This code will log a single array of results once all promises are either fulfilled or rejected. This array will obviously contain one entry for each promise (for each call to hastebin).

Comment: For me the output looks like [link](https://imgur.com/a/GZaWoDw). The thing I'm trying to achieve outputing 1 Hastebin url with all the emails. I also had to rename the "results" in the loop to "EmailResults" because results var was already declared

Comment: Exactly, that's what I said. If you want a single Hastebin, then you should move the `hastebin` call outside the `for` loop to call it only one time and pass it all the `results` concatenated.

Comment: Tried the second now now i get "emails.map is not a function" error? I'm so confused LUL. Also I have edited the question now too.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that file contains an object, not an array. Check now, should be fixed using `Object.values()`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to put all emails into just one file, rather than creating a link for each. The way to correcting this is to understand why it is doing it this way.

Let's first look at where you are creating the link (your hasebin() call), this is inside the for loop. You need to move this outside of your loop, but you want something within your loop still to create an array of the emails you wish to add to hastebin.

Based on your title, you understand this - it sounds like you have a problem with javascripts asynchronous nature, in that your call outside of the loop would not wait for the loop to finish, thus it would not yet have any data within the array.

To achieve this in Javascript we use something called a "callback".

See this example:

```
function functionOne(callbackFunction) {
    console.log("1");
    callbackFunction(); 
}

function onComplete() {
    console.log("2");
}

functionOne(onComplete);
```

The code above would call functionOne with a parameter referencing the onComplete method. functionOne gets ran (1 is printed to console), and then onComplete is called via callbackFunction() and 2 is printed to the console.

So, what does this mean for you example? Your loop should run and then have a callback which is where you create your hastebin, this will ensure your loop has finished constructing/fetching the data prior to trying to upload it.

Comment: Thanks for the explaining! I understand now. But I've already selected another answer as a solution. But thanks a lot again! And I don't know if i can choose 2 answers as a solution

Comment: Also you didn't mention how to transfer the data between each function. And yea I want to wait until the loop finish so all emails can be send with 1 Hastebin link.